# Javascript and Mysql save api data

Tags: javascript, mysql

Can someone please point me in the right direction or just tell me if it is possible to save the javascript output to a mysql database?

```
const url = 'apiUrl';
const output = document.querySelector('.output')

fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET'
}).then(function(res) {
    return res.json()
}).then(function(json) {
    console.log(json.data);
    json.data.forEach(function(val) {
        var obje = val['apiUrl.code'] + '   ';
        var objelabel = val['demarcation.label'] + '</br>';
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML += document.write(JSON.stringify(obje), JSON.stringify(objelabel) + '</br>');
        div.append(output);
    })
    WriteToFile("Documents\demarcation.json", null, output)
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

I have added some code but get and error on the require. I did try and google on how to resolve the issue but with no luck.

Comment: This looks like browser-based code (rather than server-based NodeJS code). If you need to save data to a MySQL database then you will need to send the data (via a HTTP request, probably another AJAX request using fetch()) to some server-side code (written in any language) which can then talk to the database and save the data. It is not possible to connect to a database directly from browser-based Javascript (and even if it was, it wouldn't be secure to do so).

Comment: So yes, it's possible, but you need an extra component (the server-side code) to make it work.